# How to return Jasmine unit test results as a string?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing with the Reporters, but is there a simple way to just execute my unit tests and retrieve the results as a string rather than messing with the console or the DOM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this you have to implement your own `Reporter` that will log the result and keep it in a text format. Here's a short example of how you can do it :

```
function TextReporter() {
    this.textResult = "";
}

TextReporter.prototype = new jasmine.Reporter();

TextReporter.prototype.onRunnerFinished = function (callback) {
    this.callbackEnd = callback;
};

TextReporter.prototype.reportRunnerResults = function (runner) {        
    // When all the spec are finished //
    var result = runner.results();

    this.textResult += "Test results :: (" + result.passedCount + "/" + result.totalCount + ") :: " + (result.passed() ? "passed" : "failed");
    this.textResult += "\r\n";

    if (this.callbackEnd) {
        this.callbackEnd(this.textResult);
    }
};

TextReporter.prototype.reportSuiteResults = function (suite) {
    // When a group of spec has finished running //
    var result = suite.results();
    var description = suite.description;
}

TextReporter.prototype.reportSpecResults = function(spec) {
    // When a single spec has finished running //
    var result = spec.results();

    this.textResult += "Spec :: " + spec.description + " :: " + (result.passed() ? "passed" : "failed");
    this.textResult += "\r\n";
};
```

And after that instead of using the `HtmlReporter`, you can use your `TextReporter`.

```
var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;

var txtReporter = new TextReporter();
txtReporter.onRunnerFinished(function (text) {
    // Do something with text //
});

jasmineEnv.addReporter(txtReporter);

window.onload = function() {
    jasmineEnv.execute();
};
```

If you need more information about custom reporter, all you need to know is that they have to implement the [`Reporter`](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/Reporter.js) interface.

Comment: and what about the failed test's expected and current values?